# Ternary operator with nil. How to use in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have return a ternary operator to retrieve and index as follows

```
val = (
  (@str_value.index("APPLE")).nil ? (
    (@str_value.index("DIAMOND")).nil ? @str_value.index("GARLIC") : str_value.index("DIAMOND")
  ) : @str_value.index("APPLE")
)
```

But when I run this it gives me an error.

```
undefined method `nil' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm new to Ruby. What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: The method you want is named `nil?`.

Comment: Please give a couple of examples `@str_value`/`expected_val`, this snippet is atrocious, there is without doubt a better way to write it.

Comment: For future problem solving related to this, if you don't have internet access, `nil.methods.select { |m| m.match /nil/ }` sould give you the exact method you want, or even nil.<tab><tab> from irb or rails console...

Comment: toro2k is right, `.nil?`, not `.nil`.So `(@str_value.index("APPLE")).nil? ? (` etc.

Comment: This is a terrible use of ternary statements. Use one, not many. If you feel the need for many use `if` or `case` statements. In Perl and C we'd use them liberally but this is Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@str_value.index("APPLE") || @str_value.index("DIAMOND") || @str_value.index("GARLIC")
```

Comment: that's the first refactor required but being a string probably a regexp is the second...

Comment: This will return `7` as well

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois you are right... :) but for long words.. too many time need to write `||` and `@str_value.index("XXXX")`... :) I think.. I will go with array.

Answer (score 7):

Benchmark time:

```
require 'benchmark'

def amit_kumar_gupta(str_value)
  str_value.index("APPLE") || str_value.index("DIAMOND") || str_value.index("GARLIC")
end

def priti(str_value)
  %w(APPLE DIAMOND GARLIC).map{|i| str_value.index(i)}.compact[0]
end

def borodin(str_value)
  /APPLE|DIAMOND|GARLIC/ =~ str_value
end

# I added a single anchor, based on knowledge of where the target would be, to
# show the difference an anchored search can make.

def borodin2(str_value)
  str_value[/\b (?:APPLE|DIAMOND|GARLIC) \b\Z/x]
end

STRING = ('a'..'z').to_a.join * 100
APPLE_STRING = STRING + ' APPLE'
GARLIC_STRING = STRING + ' GARLIC'
N = 100_000

puts "RUBY_VERSION = #{ RUBY_VERSION }"
puts "N = #{N}"
Benchmark.bm(15) do |b|
  b.report('amit apple') { N.times { amit_kumar_gupta(APPLE_STRING) } }
  b.report('amit garlic') { N.times { amit_kumar_gupta(GARLIC_STRING) } }
  b.report('priti apple') { N.times { priti(APPLE_STRING) } }
  b.report('priti garlic') { N.times { priti(GARLIC_STRING) } }
  b.report('borodin apple') { N.times { borodin(APPLE_STRING) } }
  b.report('borodin garlic') { N.times { borodin(GARLIC_STRING) } }
  b.report('borodin2 apple') { N.times { borodin2(APPLE_STRING) } }
  b.report('borodin2 garlic') { N.times { borodin2(GARLIC_STRING) } }
end
```

With the results for 1.9.3:

```
RUBY_VERSION = 1.9.3
N = 100000
                      user     system      total        real
amit apple        0.540000   0.000000   0.540000 (  0.539550)
amit garlic       1.560000   0.000000   1.560000 (  1.567501)
priti apple       1.670000   0.000000   1.670000 (  1.673736)
priti garlic      1.630000   0.000000   1.630000 (  1.630529)
borodin apple     0.810000   0.010000   0.820000 (  0.811853)
borodin garlic    0.810000   0.000000   0.810000 (  0.817202)
borodin2 apple    0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.223292)
borodin2 garlic   0.230000   0.000000   0.230000 (  0.225041)
```

And Ruby 2.0.0-p195:

```
RUBY_VERSION = 2.0.0
N = 100000
                      user     system      total        real
amit apple        0.250000   0.000000   0.250000 (  0.253446)
amit garlic       0.730000   0.000000   0.730000 (  0.730139)
priti apple       0.820000   0.000000   0.820000 (  0.825674)
priti garlic      0.820000   0.010000   0.830000 (  0.821391)
borodin apple     2.230000   0.000000   2.230000 (  2.240345)
borodin garlic    2.250000   0.010000   2.260000 (  2.264021)
borodin2 apple    0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (  0.197568)
borodin2 garlic   0.190000   0.000000   0.190000 (  0.197615)
```

And what did we learn (Dorothy)?:

Amit's code is taking advantage of `||` short-circuiting the tests. If `index("APPLE")` finds the value no further testing is required and processing stops. This is an immense time and CPU savings for large jobs. You can see the effect in the difference between having to search for "APPLE" vs. "GARLIC". The first returns after one test, and the second returns after three tests.

Priti's is forcing all tests whether or not the first or second found an answer, then throwing away the results that failed. This is a naive attempt and isn't how to write this sort of code.

Borodin's code shows how to test a whole bunch of different strings succinctly, but regex have a lot of overhead that can slow them down. It's interesting that v2.0-p195 was much slower that 1.9.3. I don't know if that's a bug or what, but it is significant. In the `borodin2` code I also showed how to catch full words, not just sub-strings. That is really important when doing text processing, and becomes a lot harder to do when you're NOT using regex. If you're after whole words, then regex are the only way to go in my opinion.

I added the `borodin2` test and added a single "end-of-line" anchor to show how important that little bit of knowledge about the structure of the string can be. Using `rindex` instead of `index` would improve the first four tests too, and, in all cases, they'd degrade if the target string was at the front of the search string then. That pre-knowledge is important. Scan your data and get an idea of what you're looking for and if you can find patterns to take advantage of, then your code can run a lot faster.

In my opinion, Amit's code is the best general purpose code because of the short-circuiting. Borodin's code is the easiest to extend and is faster with 1.9.3 but with 2.0 it's suffering. Personally, I'd use `borodin` or `borodin2` on the assumption that they'll figure out what slowed it down in another rev of Ruby, but YMMV. There is little difference between 2.0.0-p195 and 2.0.0-p247 on my machine so I didn't show its results. And, maybe it's a flaw in my pattern and one of the really smart Ruby folks will chime in to correct it.

---

Modifying the code to use Fruity:

```
require 'fruity'

def amit_kumar_gupta(str_value)
  str_value.index("APPLE") || str_value.index("DIAMOND") || str_value.index("GARLIC")
end

def priti(str_value)
  %w(APPLE DIAMOND GARLIC).map{|i| str_value.index(i)}.compact[0]
end

def borodin(str_value)
  /APPLE|DIAMOND|GARLIC/ =~ str_value
end

# I added a single anchor, based on knowledge of where the target would be, to
# show the difference an anchored search can make.

def borodin2(str_value)
  str_value[/\b (?:APPLE|DIAMOND|GARLIC) \b\Z/x]
end

STRING = ('a'..'z').to_a.join * 100
APPLE_STRING = STRING + ' APPLE'
GARLIC_STRING = STRING + ' GARLIC'

puts "RUBY_VERSION = #{ RUBY_VERSION }"
compare do
  amit_apple        { amit_kumar_gupta(APPLE_STRING)  }  
  amit_garlic       { amit_kumar_gupta(GARLIC_STRING) } 
  priti_apple       { priti(APPLE_STRING)             }             
  priti_garlic      { priti(GARLIC_STRING)            }            
  borodin_apple     { borodin(APPLE_STRING)           }           
  borodin_garlic    { borodin(GARLIC_STRING)          }          
  borodin2_apple    { borodin2(APPLE_STRING)          }          
  borodin2_garlic   { borodin2(GARLIC_STRING)         }         
end

RUBY_VERSION = 2.1.0
Running each test 4096 times. Test will take about 6 seconds.
amit_apple is faster than amit_garlic by 2.6x ± 0.1
amit_garlic is faster than borodin2_garlic by 10.000000000000009% ± 1.0% (results differ: 2601 vs GARLIC)
borodin2_garlic is similar to borodin2_apple (results differ: GARLIC vs APPLE)
borodin2_apple is faster than priti_apple by 39.99999999999999% ± 1.0% (results differ: APPLE vs 2601)
priti_apple is similar to priti_garlic
priti_garlic is faster than borodin_apple by 10x ± 0.1
borodin_apple is faster than borodin_garlic by 2.0000000000000018% ± 1.0%
```

Returns:

```
RUBY_VERSION = 2.1.0
Running each test 4096 times. Test will take about 6 seconds.
amit_apple is faster than amit_garlic by 2.6x ± 0.1
amit_garlic is faster than borodin2_garlic by 10.000000000000009% ± 1.0% (results differ: 2601 vs GARLIC)
borodin2_garlic is similar to borodin2_apple (results differ: GARLIC vs APPLE)
borodin2_apple is faster than priti_apple by 39.99999999999999% ± 1.0% (results differ: APPLE vs 2601)
priti_apple is similar to priti_garlic
priti_garlic is faster than borodin_apple by 10x ± 0.1
borodin_apple is faster than borodin_garlic by 2.0000000000000018% ± 1.0%
```

Comment: I was looking for you captain :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
val = /APPLE|DIAMOND|GARLIC/ =~ @str_value
```

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method '%' for /APPLE|DIAMOND|GARLIC/:Regexp`

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta: Sorry. Fixed.

Comment: Very nice! obligatorycharacters

Comment: Better would be `/\b (?:APPLE|DIAMOND|GARLIC) \b/x` which catches whole words not just substrings.

Comment: @theTinMan: Probably. But I wanted to write something that was equivalent to the original post (with the bugs fixed).

Answer (score 2):

[`String#index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-index)

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the given substring or pattern (regexp) in str. ***Returns nil if not found***. If the second parameter is present, it specifies the position in the string to begin the search.

Use `@str_value.index("APPLE")).nil? ?` instead.

*You missed one `?` here `@str_value.index("APPLE")).nil ?`*

See that `nil` object has `nil?` method not `nil` method:

```
nil.methods.grep(/nil/)
# => [nil?]
```

So the fix of your expression is :

```
@str_value = "I love APPLE"
val = @str_value.index("APPLE") ? (@str_value.index("DIAMOND") ? @str_value.index("GARLIC") : @str_value.index("DIAMOND")) : @str_value.index("APPLE")
p val # => nil
```

Better is :

```
@str_value = "I love APPLE"
%w(APPLE DIAMOND GARLIC).map{|i| @str_value.index(i)}.compact[0]
#>> 7
```

Comment: You really want to avoid nested ternary patterns... You should not write more than one `condition ? value1 : value2`. In this case, I think @amit answer's is more appropriate.

Comment: Yes you are right about the `nil` / `nil?` method thing. Just wanted to talk about the nested ternary pattern :)

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois Your first comment causes a *down-vote* to me. This answer shouldn't deserve that.. :(

Comment: "Your first comment causes a down-vote to me."? Then don't put in code like that. Blaming the commenter for your bad choice is silly because the comment is correct; Nested ternary isn't good in any language, and is avoided especially in Ruby.

Comment: @theTinMan I have shown him the fix to get himself show where was the mistake. After that I have also shown him,what is *better* approach,I think. I taught him first what's the mistake is, then shown him the good possible code. I don't know where I was wrong.

Comment: You blamed the commenter for a down-vote. The answer causes the down-vote, not the comment. Without comments how would you learn and improve your code? It's good code that leads to good answers which lead to up-votes. Stifling comments to avoid down-votes to sooth your feelings isn't good for you, for the OP, or for Stack Overflow. Accept downvotes as a gentle criticism and be thankful when you get a comment that criticizes and explains the problem so you can learn and improve your quality. It's all a good thing.